# Making a one String line calculator

Tags: java, regex, calculator

right now I am making a one string calculator, learning regex and i have some questions.

With 2 number like: 2 + 2, the output is going to be 4, but if i try to input 3 numbers: 2 + 2 + 2, the output will be 4, ignoring the third number, but i Am going though operands.length.

the other one, if i try to put the first number as negative like: - 2 + 2, it will give me an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "".

String[] operators = input.split("\s*-?\w+\s*"); doesnt really work but why?

```
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();

            boolean ifExit = false;
            boolean ifHelp = false;
            boolean ifEmpty = false;
            boolean ifOneNumber = false;

            String[] operators = input.split("\\s*\\w+\\s*");
            String[] operands = input.split("\\s*[+-]+\\s*");

            int result = 0;

            if (operands[0].matches("/exit")) {
                ifExit = true;
                System.out.println("Bye!");
                break;
            } else if (operands[0].matches("/help")) {
                ifHelp = true;
                System.out.println("The program calculates the sum of numbers");
            } else if (operands[0].matches("")) {
                ifEmpty = true;
            } else if (operands[0].matches("[0-9]+") && operands.length == 1) {
                ifOneNumber = true;
                result += Integer.parseInt(operands[0]);
                System.out.println(result);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < operands.length; i++) {
                result = Integer.parseInt(operands[0]);

                if (operators[i].matches("[+]")) {
                    allBooleansAreFalse(ifHelp, ifEmpty, ifOneNumber);
                    result += Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
                } else if (operators[i].matches("[-]")){
                    allBooleansAreFalse(ifHelp, ifEmpty, ifOneNumber);
                    result -= Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
                } else if (operators[i].matches("[+]{2,1000}")) {
                    allBooleansAreFalse(ifHelp, ifEmpty, ifOneNumber);
                    result += Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
                } else if (operators[i].matches("[-]{2}")) {
                    allBooleansAreFalse(ifHelp, ifEmpty, ifOneNumber);
                    result += Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
                } else if (operators[i].matches("[-]{3}")) {
                    allBooleansAreFalse(ifHelp, ifEmpty, ifOneNumber);
                    result -= Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
                }
            }
            if (ifExit == true) {
                break;
            } else if (ifExit == false && ifHelp == false && ifEmpty == false && ifOneNumber == false) {
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void allBooleansAreFalse(boolean ifHelp, boolean ifEmpty, boolean ifOneNumber) {
        ifHelp = false;
        ifEmpty = false;
        ifOneNumber = false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? A string of the form `7 + 9` will produce two operands and one operator. But you loop over `operators[i]` and `operands[i]` starting at `i = 1`. So, `operand[1]` is `9` (correct` but to determine what to do with it you look at `operator[1]` which should throw an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: As you loop through the operands you keep resetting the `result` to the first operand so that ignores previous additions for example.  So 2 + 3 + 4 most likely produces 6.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the first problem by adding this code just before the for loop:

```
else if (operands[0].matches("[0-9]")) {
                result = Integer.parseInt(operands[0]);
            }
```

and removing this code inside the for loop:

```
result = Integer.parseInt(operands[0]);
```

now I need to fix the problem with the negative numbers where if the first number is negative: -2 + 2 it gives me an error, anyone?